# To deduce that Roberta is not tall

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How do I deduce?

Suppose we know that:

- if Paolo is thin, then Carlo is not blonde or Roberta is not tall
- if Roberta is tall then Sandra is lovely
- if Sandra is lovely and Carlo is blonde then Paolo is thin
- Carlo is blonde

Can we deduce that Roberta is not tall?

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can. We would do it by contradiction.

Suppose that Roberta were tall. Then, by the second statement, Sandra is lovely. By the third statement, Paolo is thin.

By the first statement, either "Carlo is not blonde" or "Roberta is not tall" must be true. But neither of these are.

Hence, we can conclude that Roberta is not tall, which is consistent with the hypotheses. In that case, nothing can be said about either Sandra or Paolo (which is a pity, I'd have loved to know Sandra).

Comment: "tall", "lovely", "blonde", and "thin" all make for predicates with imprecise boundaries.  It seems that you made the supposition that *were* it the case that Roberta *was* tall, and then conclude that she is tall on that assumption.  But, this only makes sense in general if everything that is possible is actual (actualism).  Also, people who have studied imprecise predicates do NOT have a logic which allows you to introduce a hypothesis and then discharge that hypothesis (there is no Deduction Meta-Theorem, properly speaking, in fuzzy logic).

Comment: I agree with you, but for this question I  thought we might as well assume that they are precise rather than vague.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

You have two options. Roberta is not tall is true or false. If it is false (it means that Roberta is tall) we can deduce from first statement that Paolo is thin is false (how?). This means that Sandra is lovely and Carlo is blonde must be false (from third statement). Since Carlo is blonde is true, Sandra is lovely must be false. Then, from second statement we get that Roberta is tall is false.

So, if we start with Roberta is tall we obtain Roberta is not tall! Not possible.

Now, you only have to show that Roberta is not tall is possible.

Comment: What I understood from you @MaliMish that each statements depend on each other.  should I read those statements as nested condition?
I think Carlo is certainly blonde as mentioned in 4th statement.

"Paolo is thin is false (how?). This means that Sandra is lovely and Carlo is blonde must be false (from third statement).". How sandra and carlo must be false? according to truth table or something else.

also could you tell me a book for these type of statements with solution.

Comment: Third statement is: $(S\wedge C)\rightarrow P$. We know that Paolo is thin is false, so we have $(S\wedge C)\rightarrow \text{false}$. Since each statement must be true, $(S\wedge C)$ must be false - if it were true, third statement would be false. Try searching for compound conditional statements for more explanations. Or look for any book that has a chapter called Propositional Logic (or something similar).

Comment: how we know that paolo is thin is false?
if S^C is false then paolo is thin is true then third statement would be true.

Comment: But we know that Paolo is thin is false from first statement. 1)Suppose that Roberta is not tall is false (so, Roberta is tall). 2) Then we obtain that Paolo is not thin. 3) Then we obtain that Sandra is not lovely. 4) Then we obtain that Roberta is not tall. That is not possible because we started the reasoning with assumption that Roberta is tall. In conclusion, Roberta cannot be tall.

Comment: it means we need to prove by contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Writing the statements symbolically, using $P$ for "Paolo is thin", $C$ for "Carlo is blonde", $S$ for "Sandra is lovely" and $R$ for "Roberta is tall":
$$P\to(\neg C\lor\neg R)\\
R\to S\\
(S\land C)\to P\\
C$$
Substituting the value of C into the first and third sentences and then simplifying we get
$$P\to\neg R\\
R\to S\\
S\to P$$
These can be chained to get the single proposition
$$R\to\neg R$$
from which follows $\neg R$, i.e. Roberta can be deduced as not tall from the given statements.

Answer (score 0):

We know that:

- $\text{Thin}(P)\implies\neg\text{Blonde}(C)\vee\neg\text{Tall}(R)$
- $\text{Tall}(R)\implies\text{Lovely}(S)$
- $\text{Lovely}(S)\wedge\text{Blonde}(C)\implies\text{Thin}(P)$
- $\text{Blonde}(C)$ is true

---

Assume by contradiction that Roberta is tall.

Therefore $\text{Tall}(R)$ is true.

Therefore $\text{Lovely}(S)$ is true.

Therefore, since $\text{Blonde}(C)$ is true, $\text{Thin}(P)$ is true.

Therefore, since $\neg\text{Blonde}(C)$ is false, $\neg\text{Tall}(R)$ is true.

Which contradicts the assumption, hence Roberta is not tall.

Comment: But we still have to show that Roberta is not tall is possible. If we have statement $A\wedge \sim A$, and assume $A$ we get contradiction. That does not mean that $\sim A$ is true because it also gives contradiction.

Comment: @MaliMish: In that case, the entire system must be false.